# Accept Self-signed SSL certificate in icenium using jquery to make ajax calls to a wcf rest service?

Tags: ajax, wcf, ssl, telerik

I have an application in icenium that call a rest/json wcf service using jquery. When the calls are made using a non-encrypted connection (http) everything behaves as it should. However, when I use a ssl encrypted connection (https) all my ajax calls fail. I figure this is related to the self-signed certificate I use to test.

I was wondering if there was any way to accept self-signed certificates. I even installed the certificates on my iPad and still can't get it to work.

Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that this will necessarily work for Icenium. However, I had the same problem with jquery and a self-signed certificate in a good old-fashioned HTML page. I discovered that I had to change my jquery script source to use https rather than http. Everything then worked fine.

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```